# ThreeJS is cutting the my rendered model in half

Tags: typescript, three.js, camera

The 3D model that I render isn't rendering past half the height of the my scene. I use the `OrthoCamera` class which looks like this. When I change the near value to -2000, the model gets rendered completely.

```
export class OrthoCamera extends THREE.OrthographicCamera {

  constructor(
    renderingContext: HTMLCanvasElement,

  ) {
    super(
    //   FOV,
    renderingContext.clientWidth / - 2,
    renderingContext.clientWidth / 2,
    
    renderingContext.clientHeight / 2,
    renderingContext.clientHeight / - 2,
    
    0, // near
    2000 // far
    
    );

  }
```

In the `AnimalGenerator` class I instantiate a Raycaster, however the Raycaster doesn't work past the same point like the OrthoCamera before I changed the near value from 0 to -2000.
Even when I change the near value inside of the AnimalGenerator to match the same values it doesn't work.

```
export class AnimalsGenerator 
{
    private animals: THREE.Group;
    private rayCaster: THREE.Raycaster;
    private animalEventDispatcher: AnimalEventDispatcher;

    public constructor(animalEventDispatcher: AnimalEventDispatcher)
    {
        this.animalEventDispatcher = animalEventDispatcher;
        this.animals = new THREE.Group();
        this.rayCaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.rayCaster.near = -2000;
        this.rayCaster.far = 2000;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780096/orthographic-camera-is-cutting-rendered-scene-in-half](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77780096/orthographic-camera-is-cutting-rendered-scene-in-half) Duplicate question